# Inductive definition over closed type family

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass, type-families

This is more or the less the functionality I want to implement:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilyDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeInType             #-}

type family ReturnType arr where
  ReturnType (a -> b) = ReturnType b
  ReturnType a = a

type family ReplaceReturnType t r where
  ReplaceReturnType (a -> b) r = a -> ReplaceReturnType b r
  ReplaceReturnType _ r = r

class CollectArgs f where
  collectArgs :: ((forall r. ReplaceReturnType f r -> r) -> ReturnType f) -> f

instance CollectArgs f => CollectArgs (a -> f) where
  collectArgs :: ((forall r. (a -> ReplaceReturnType f r) -> r) -> ReturnType f) -> a -> f
  collectArgs f a = collectArgs (\ap -> f (\k -> ap (k a)))

instance (ReturnType a ~ a, ReplaceReturnType a dummy ~ dummy) => CollectArgs a where
  collectArgs :: ((forall r. ReplaceReturnType a r -> r) -> a) -> a
  collectArgs f = f id
```

What I eventually want to do with this is to write functions which are polymorphic in the number of incoming arguments, while they don't have to be part of a type class definition (which would correspond to `printf` var args style). So, for example:

```
wrapsVariadicFunction :: (CollectArgs f) => f -> Int -> f
wrapsVariadicFunction f config = collectArgs $ \apply -> 
  if odd config 
    then error "odd config... are you nuts?!"
    else apply f
```

Only that the return type of `f` might not coicide with that of `wrapsVariadicFunction`.

Now, in a perfect world where I can associate a type class with a closed type family (a closed type class, so to speak), this would be easy to implement, because the connection `ReplaceReturnType a r ~ r` would be clear.

Since I can't state that connection, it is, quite understandably, not clear to GHC 8.2.1:

```
    * Could not deduce: ReplaceReturnType a r ~ r
      from the context: (ReturnType a ~ a,
                         ReplaceReturnType a dummy ~ dummy)
        bound by the instance declaration
      `r' is a rigid type variable bound by
        a type expected by the context:
          forall r. ReplaceReturnType a r -> r
      Expected type: ReplaceReturnType a r -> r
        Actual type: r -> r
    * In the first argument of `f', namely `id'
      In the expression: f id
      In an equation for `collectArgs': collectArgs f = f id
    * Relevant bindings include
        f :: (forall r. ReplaceReturnType a r -> r) -> a
        collectArgs :: ((forall r. ReplaceReturnType a r -> r) -> a) -> a
   |
29 |   collectArgs f = f id
   |
```

A solution here would be universally quantifying over `dummy` in the instance context, but that's not possible (yet, judging from what I saw at ICFP). Also it's really cumbersome.

So, the actual question here is: How do I associate a value-level definition with a closed type family, much like a closed type class? Or is this impossible because types cannot be erased anymore? If so, is there some other workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard trick to have these type classes that look like they are overlapping is to add a second parameter to the typeclass which will be distinct in each instance and whose value can be computed from the other ones.

The idea distilled to its very core is as follows (we need some scary extensions like `UndecidableInstances` but that's fine: we're writing total programs):

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances   #-}

type family IsBase arr :: Bool where
  IsBase (a -> b) = 'False
  IsBase a        = 'True

class SillyId a b where
  sillyId :: IsBase a ~ b => a -> a

instance SillyId b (IsBase b) => SillyId (a -> b) 'False where
  sillyId f = \x -> sillyId (f x)

instance SillyId b 'True where
  sillyId t = t
```

Now, in your case it's a bit more complicated because you not only want this extra argument to do the dispatch, you also want other type level functions to reduce based on it. The trick is simply... to define these functions in terms of that dispatch!

Of course a type level `Bool` won't do anymore: you'll need to keep all of the information around. So instead of `IsBase` you'll have `IsArrow`:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances   #-}

type family IsArrow arr :: Either (*, *) * where
  IsArrow (a -> b) = 'Left '(a, b)
  IsArrow a        = 'Right a

type family ReturnType arr where
  ReturnType ('Left '(a, b)) = ReturnType (IsArrow b)
  ReturnType ('Right a)      = a

type family ReplaceReturnType t r where
  ReplaceReturnType ('Left '(a, b)) r = a -> ReplaceReturnType (IsArrow b) r
  ReplaceReturnType _               r = r

class CollectArgs f (f' :: Either (*, *) *) where
  collectArgs :: IsArrow f ~ f' => ((forall r. ReplaceReturnType f' r -> r) -> ReturnType f') -> f

instance CollectArgs f (IsArrow f) => CollectArgs (a -> f) ('Left '(a, f)) where
  collectArgs :: ((forall r. (a -> ReplaceReturnType (IsArrow f) r) -> r) -> ReturnType (IsArrow f)) -> a -> f
  collectArgs g a = collectArgs (\ap -> g (\k -> ap (k a)))

instance CollectArgs a ('Right a) where
  collectArgs :: IsArrow a ~ 'Right a => ((forall r. ReplaceReturnType (IsArrow a) r -> r) -> a) -> a
  collectArgs f = f id
```

And voilà. You can of course define type synonyms for `ReplaceReturnType (IsArrow a) r` to make the notations a bit lighter but that's the gist of it.

Comment: Thanks, that was eye-opening! `Either` doesn't really work here, though, because it is non-recursive: `IsArrow (Int -> Int -> Int) ~ 'Left '(Int, Int -> Int))`. But this variant works: http://lpaste.net/234466362087440384. Would you mind editing your answer? I did so earlier, but appearently that's not why you edit stuff on SO.

Comment: I don't get it: `Either` works just fine (all of the code typechecks). I guess the question is whether you want to perform the whole reification ahead of time or whether you're happy with doing it on demand by making recursive calls via `IsArrow` as I do.

Comment: Oh, in fact you're right! The type error I was experiencing was due to something completely different. I tried `collectArgs (\apply -> apply (+)) 4 5` and was thrown off by the type error (`No instance for (Num ())`) and started digging for the cause, when I hit that strange reduction. But all that was missing to get it running was a type annotation, e.g. `collectArgs (\apply -> apply (+)) 4 5 :: Int` evaluates to 9.

Comment: By the way: Is it possible to completely discharge `CollectArgs` constraints by defining something like `class CollectArgs f (IsArrow f) => CollectArgs' f` and somehow tell GHC that we always have a dictionary for that available? I don't really want this to leak into user code. I guess what I'm looking for is an elegant way to package all constraints up in a user friendly manner.

Comment: Ah, that won't work because of erasure... Still, I wonder how to package this up nicely.

Comment: I'm afraid the error messages will always be horrible: you can wrap the internals in constraint synonyms using `{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds        #-}` to recover the interface you had in mind to begin with but if there's an error, they'll be unfolded in the error message :/

Comment: By the way, another thing you could do instead is use the notion of [`Domains`](https://github.com/agda/agda/blob/master/src/full/Agda/Utils/TypeLevel.hs#L81) , [`Products` and `Arrows`](https://github.com/agda/agda/blob/master/src/full/Agda/Utils/TypeLevel.hs#L69)
 and [`Currying`](https://github.com/agda/agda/blob/master/src/full/Agda/Utils/TypeLevel.hs#L99) to convert between them. Instead of `ReplaceReturnType t r` you'd simply write `Products (Domains t) -> r` or `Arrows (Domains t) r` if you want the curried form. Hopefully this would lead to clearer error messages for your users.

Comment: That sounds like the more principled approach. Thanks for that very valuable pointer!

Comment: Wow, that file is pure gold. I'm learning so much right now about how to properly do things at the type level in a way that I'm used to.